# Configuring multiple one-to-many relations between same entities when the relations propagate deeper

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 6 classes where the first class Money, goes deep 5 levels with objects. Whatever I try I cannot get this representation, so I hope someone would be kind to offer some help. At least for first 2,3 levels then I can continue.

```
public class Money
{
    public Money()
    {
       Dollars = new HashSet<MoneyDetails>();
       Pesos = new HashSet<MoneyDetails>();
       Pounds = new HashSet<MoneyDetails>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MoneyDetails> Dollars { get; }
    public virtual ICollection<MoneyDetails> Pesos { get; }
    public virtual ICollection<MoneyDetails> Pounds { get; }
    public string Note { get; }
}
    
    
public class MoneyDetails
{
    public MoneyDetails()
    {
        Valuations = new HashSet<Valuations>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuations 
{
    public Valuations ()
    {
        Lows = new HashSet<Deep>();
        Highs = new HashSet<Deep>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sum { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Deep> Lows { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Deep> Highs { get; set; }
}

public class Deep
{
    public Deep()
    {
        Shallows = new HashSet<Shallow>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shallow> Shallows { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT :**
I'm using `Entity Framework Core`.
Following is the configuration I tried myself.
You can see below how I started, I just don't know how to go deeper into objects and make relationships between them so they are connected.

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Money> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Money");
     builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

     builder.HasMany(s => s.Dollars)
                .WithOne(ad => ad.Money)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.MoneyId);

     builder.HasMany(s => s.Pesos)
                .WithOne(ad => ad.Money)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.MoneyId);

    builder.HasMany(s => s.Pounds)
               .WithOne(ad => ad.Money)
               .HasForeignKey(i => i.MoneyId);

}
```

Comment: Is it EF Core, or EF 6? And how exactly have you tried? Could you share some code? Also, "offer some help" in what way? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @atiyar added more details, this is EF Core. I started building Configuration file as show, but don't know how to build further since object is deep 6 levels inside.

Comment: Please check the `Edit` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using -

```
.WithOne(ad => ad.Money)
.HasForeignKey(i => i.MoneyId);
```

in your configuration code, but you don't have a `Money` navigation property or a `MoneyId` foreign-key property in `MoneyDetails`.

Since you are not using navigation and foreign-key properties in any of your entity models, I'd suggest *not* to configure the relations manually. Configure other properties in the `Configure` method if you need, but do not configure the relations. That way, EF will automatically create nullable foreign-keys in your tables and use them as `Shadow Property`.

**EDIT - A better solution for you :**
Even though the suggestion above will create all your tables with all the relations, I'm confused about how you plan to use those relations. For example, in the `Money` entity model `Dollars`, `Pesos`, `Pounds` are all collections of `MoneyDetails`. Therefore, all the following queries -

```
var money = myDbContext.Money.Include(p=> p.Dollars).FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Id == someId);
var money = myDbContext.Money.Include(p=> p.Pesos).FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Id == someId);
var money = myDbContext.Money.Include(p=> p.Pounds).FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Id == someId);
```

will give you the same result - the `Money` with the specified `Id`, with a list of *all* related `MoneyDetails`. So, there's no point of having three collection properties and three different relations.

Try the following approach to filter related data (you need `EF Core 5.0`) -

1. Create `enum` to identify the entity type -

```
public enum MoneyDetailsType { Dollar = 1, Peso = 2, Pound = 3 }
public enum DeepType { High = 1, Low = 2 }
```

2. Modify your entity models like -

```
public class Money
{
    public Money()
    {
       MoneyDetails = new HashSet<MoneyDetails>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; }
    public virtual ICollection<MoneyDetails> MoneyDetails { get; set; }
}
    
public class MoneyDetails
{
    public MoneyDetails()
    {
        Valuations = new HashSet<Valuations>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public MoneyDetailsType Type { get; set; }  // added - type
    public int MoneyId { get; set; }            // added - foreign-key
    
    public Money Money { get; set; }            // added - navigation property (optional)
    public virtual ICollection<Valuations> Valuations { get; set; }
}

public class Valuations 
{
    public Valuations ()
    {
        Deeps = new HashSet<Deep>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sum { get; set; }
    public int MoneyDetailsId { get; set; }         // added - foreign-key
    
    public MoneyDetails MoneyDetails { get; set; }  // added - navigation property (optional)
    public virtual ICollection<Deep> Deeps { get; set; }
}

public class Deep
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public DeepType Type { get; set; }          // added - type
    public int ValuationsId { get; set; }       // added - foreign-key
    
    public Valuations Valuations { get; set; }  // added - navigation property (optional)
}
```

Notice, in `Deep` entity, currently you have `Data` as of type `object` which is not allowed. You have to change it to some primitive type. I'm using it as `string`. I have also omitted the `Shallows` property since you haven't added the `Shallow` model.

Your configuration methods should look like -

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Money> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Money");
     builder.HasMany(p => p.MoneyDetails)
                .WithOne(p => p.Money)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.MoneyId);
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MoneyDetails> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("MoneyDetails");
     builder.Property(p => p.Type).IsRequired(true).HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<MoneyDetailsType>());
     builder.HasMany(p => p.Valuations)
                .WithOne(p => p.MoneyDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.MoneyDetailsId);
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Valuations> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Valuations");
     builder.HasMany(p => p.Deeps)
                .WithOne(p => p.Valuations)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ValuationsId);
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Deep> builder)
{
     builder.ToTable("Deep");
     builder.Property(p => p.Type).IsRequired(true).HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<DeepType>());
}
```

If you don't want to include the navigation properties in your entity models, then you can just keep the `.WithOne()` method empty in your configuration, like -

```
builder.HasMany(p => p.MoneyDetails)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.MoneyId);
```

Now you can query like -

```
var money = myDbContext.Money
            .Include(p=> p.MoneyDetails.Where(r=> r.Type == MoneyDetailsType.Dollar))
            .FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Id == someId);
```

and it will give you the `Money` with a list of only `Dollar` type `MoneyDetails`.